# calling a php function from another file with passed data remaining intact not working

Tags: php, function

EDIT - I know the query is good and that the functions themselves are good because they are used elsewhere on fileA.

I need to call a function and its value from another file. There are plenty of SO articles about this but I need the function call to include passed data that comes into the function I am trying to call. it is giving me a false error so obviously I am not passing this correctly.

I am trying to call `endresult` on my fileB. I have included the fileA in fileB like so `require_once __DIR__ . '/../fileA.php';`

Then I have called the function `endresult` like this:

```
 $endResult = endresult($idxx);
```

I have also tried just `endresult()` and using the `global $endResult`

These all produce `bool(false)` so is not being done correctly. What is the proper way to do this?

The function I am trying to call in fileA (its original file)

```
function endresult($idxx){
    global $endResult;
    $resultx = Resultx($idxx);
    $endResult = end($resultx);
    return $endResult;
}
```

The two functions that feeds the above:

```
function totalResult($idxx){
    $idcount = $idxx;
    return count(resultx($idcount));
}

function resultx($idxx) {
    global $wpdb, $resultx;
    $idr = $idxx;
    return $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT * 
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}custom_form as cc 
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}custom_formx as cs 
        ON cc.fsid ='$idr'
        WHERE cs.fid=%d", $idr));
}
```

Comment: Can you describe the flow here? are you trying to call: `$resultx = Resultx($idxx);`?

Comment: I am trying to call the endresult. I have edited above for clarity.

Comment: could you add the code block where ` $endResult = endresult($idxx);` lives please

Comment: Thanks it is the first code block above.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have to use the global $idxx on fileB. It doesnt transfer with the function itself and has to be recalled on fileB